# Is there a way to stop bosses resetting health when you die?

Tags: pc, borderlands

I play solo since I don't have any friends to play with. When I played it on the PS3 if I died I would find the boss had recovered their health meaning at times I would have to use trickery and exploits to make fights easier (ie. shooting at cars with a rocket launcher before going over a ramp, hiding under shelter and sniping Mothrak, getting one of Nine-Toes Skags to just stand there and yell and not come after me, using the Scorpio as a decoy).

One of my pet peeves with the final boss was how it's "stages" would reveal the more damage you did to it, getting it down to 3/4's it had all it's tentacles out but then I died, I came back and lo and behold it had all of them and had full health so I was being attacked even more than I was the first time.

Now I just got this on PC, likewise I don't have any friends and my PC doesn't connect to the internet so unless I go to a lan party (which is like never) I'll be going though this on my own. So far employing the same tricks as my play though on PS3 is working (glitching Nine-toes Skags, sniping all the skags around Scar) but I am wondering; is there a way to prevent Bosses recovering all their health when I die?

NOTE: I mainly ask for PC since I did get the game for PC as well for the sake of keeping my dad off my PS3

Comment: Bosses also regen health if you leave the local area (not fast travel out of the whole map zone) for just a little bit and return, even without dying yourself. I think simply moving out of their "activation" zone (the area in which they still pursue you) does trigger that instant full health regen on bosses. It seems even apply to mini-bosses like BadAsses. I've heard there's an ini file setting (bBossesRegenHealthOnReset) that changes that, but I haven't tested exactly what it does.

Answer (score 5):

This is (I believe) an intended behaviour. When you die you have full health and shields as well as (if I remember correctly) full ammo. If the boss didn't restore to full health on PC death, players who have an abundace of cash could just die on purpose in order to replenish ammo, making the boss fight meaningless.

As far as I know there is no method (outside of modding, if possible) to change this behaviour in-game.

Comment: When i fought Sledge i died several times and never did my ammo recover, i know cause one time i had about 10 bullets left in my SMG which i still had when i repawned, as far as i know only your Health and Shields recover after death. i had 10k and only a bit was taken out when i died but a lot more was spent refilling my ammo than me ever dying. if Ammo does regenerate when you die could you explain the trigger for that as i noted above it never happened

Comment: Ammo doesn't regenerate when you respawn. But kill some mobs and you will recover it quickly.

Answer (score -1):

there is no way to stop boss from restoring all of his health after you die. The best possible way to beat every boss is to fight with friends and at least one of them needs to be alive and around the boss at all times so the boss will not restore all of its health after the whole team will die.